# Can 'atypical' be used for 'difficult'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

*Atypical*, so far as I know, means irregular, unusual or not typical/normal. Here in India, people generally use 'typical' to mean *difficult* or *hard*. (A question about that was also asked here some four  years back by an Indian.) I understand now that typical cannot be used in that sense. But on that note, can 'atypical' be used to mean *difficult* or *hard*? For example,

*The teacher dictated the whole passage orally, but wrote some atypical words on blackboard.*
*Her new song is quite atypical.* (in the sense of being difficult to sing)

Comment: Perhaps some Indians who don't really speak English very well have simply conflated ***atypical*** with the idiomatic use of ***unusual*** - a common word that *in context* (such as both of your examples) may be taken to imply "little-known, [hence] difficult". But in general if someone chooses to use the less common ***atypical*** that's because they *don't* really want that particular association. An example may be dismissed as "atypical", so it doesn't affect the validity of some general principle, say - it's not "hard", just "irrelevant".

Comment: The only way I can see _atypical_ being used to denote "difficult" would be through context. Just because something is unusual doesn't mean it will be more difficult. It can mean that  though, if a test is written using atypical words and the test taker doesn't understand... that would make the test more difficult.

Comment: This question can be answered with a dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your comment seems like an answer to me

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps this is a dialectical difference. I would not want to assume it is a mistake.

Comment: @Zach: I have quite a few "Indian" neighbours, but when discussing the use of English, they (or at least, the ones I *talk* to) are only interested in speaking the same way as the rest of us. I don't really know much about what passes for acceptable or "normal" in Indian English as used over there. I just know a few usages I would characterise as "marked, unusual, atypical" which they're usually keen to shuck off in their newly-adopted homeland. So my comment above is pure speculation, nothing more.

Comment: When someone says "typical" in your dialect, is it with a feeling of exasperation? ("I had to fly back to India and spent a full day waiting for my passport stamp." "Typical.") If there's a sense of irony behind the word, that might explain how "typical" received a "difficult" connotation.

Comment: Well then, let me add that they generally use typical as synonymous with Difficult, in cases when the object being discussed is _far from usual_, in nature, difficulty level, etc. In the two examples that I mentioned above, they would easily use the word _typical_. (I'm obviously not talking about excellent English speakers, but they can be called better English speakers anyway. [The earlier question I cited](http://bit.ly/1YfMsRq) was also not answered well since nobody knew that it's actually the case.) All I want to know is whether _atypical_ fits in the two examples I gave.

Comment: @Jatin: This is getting really confusing! Can you please edit your question text (or title) so we know for sure whether you're asking about ***typical*** or ***atypical**?* Many Anglophones often use *Typical!* as an exclamatory expression of exasperation (with the sense of *Your lack of co-operation is just what I would expect from you!*, for example). An awful lot of those people won't even *know* the word ***atypical***, which is orders of magnitude less common.

Answer (score 2):

No.

In a comment, rajah9 gave an example of having to wait a day for a passport stamp.  When someone characterizes a full-day wait for a passport stamp as typical, it is not to say that the wait was difficult or hard. Rather, it means that the wait exemplifies the inefficiency of the border agency, or of some other aspect of the trip.

In other words, despite the wait having been unfortunate and wrong it was not unusual, or at least not unexpected.

As Keelon notes, in your test example, *atypical* does not mean "difficult" or "hard"; it means *unusual.*  The implication of difficulty arises from the context.  Someone might just as well find atypical items in a shopping bag without any implication of difficulty.